# How to structure components?

Tags: reactjs, calendar, modal-dialog, fullcalendar

I have this calendar call scheduler project where you can schedule call on a specific date at a specific time. I am getting data from an api telling which time slots are already unavailable. What I want to do is click on a specific date which opens a modal that shows which time slots are available and which are not. Then a user can pick a time slot available and book it, which will be saved in a database and that time slot will then become unavailable. I am using this library called full calendar which lets you click on dates. What I am confused about is should I use like one component for the modal and pass it the api data and database data merge it to check slots availability every time a date is clicked or should I create a list of components for each date and pass the specific component corresponding to the date clicked to the modal? I don't how I would know which component to pass also in this scenario? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't query the API every time the modal is called–unless you are 100% sure the user is the only person who can change the calendar–you risk the information on the modal being out of date.

FWIW, even if I was 100% sure I would still query the API every time; if you're not going to do that why use an API in the first place?